# Xampp Cannot Access mySQL/Apache with my IP

Tags: mysql, xampp

Lately i cannot access my xampp mySQL/apache server when i call `127.0.0.1(or my Network IP)\phpmyadmin` but when i call `localhost\phpmyadmin` IT works...any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for *hosts* file which contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names.

It needs enteries something like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

in order to resolve your ip to *localhost*..

It is available in *inx as well as in windows..

Comment: thanks..you answer is one of the solutions...aside from that i discovered i have the same IP address in the network...which gives the crap..